# CSV exporting all data from JSON when i only want some of it. Python

Tags: python, csv

I'm a bit confused as to what is happening with this code. i am making a python code that displays in a TKInter screen information from a json file withing a specific range, this data can then be turned into a CSV file for work in excel or access, I'm using a if warntime (time in hours since the last update of the data inside the json file) is less that errorhours (the time specified in an entry box, or 48 as a default) then the code makes an entry for each item in the main JSON file

here's what's weird though, its working perfect everywhere, except the CSV export. the tk display, number counter, all prints, literally everything is working correctly except the CSV output,

in my test I'm using a json containing 10 items in the json data (real life will be 100s) and if i enter errorhours as 200 i then get (everywhere) 5 results, however when i look at the exported csv file i see all 10 entries in the json. if i manually remove them in the json to say 7 and i re run it, i get 5 entries everywhere but all 7 in the json are written to the csv

any idea how i can limit it so that the CSV export only exports the correct data?

```
for item in data['People']:
    # WarnTimeC is calculated here but the code is irelevent for the problem so ive removed it
    # ErrorHours is gathered from an entry box 
    if WarnTimeC < ErrorHours:
      CSVName = 'API_Programs/Output CSV/CSV_Output_' + str(datetime.now().strftime('%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M_%S')) + '.csv'
      with open(CSVName, "w", newline="") as file:
                csv_file = csv.writer(file)       
                csv_file.writerow([
                        'First_Name',
                        'Last_Name',
                        'City',
                        'Job',
                        'Revenue',
                        'Last_Update',
                        'API_CHECK',
                        ]) 
                for item in data['People']:
                 if WarnTimeC < ErrorHours:
                  csv_file.writerow([
                    item['general'].get('FName', 'N/A'),
                    item['general'].get('LName', 'N/A'),
                    item['specific'].get('City', 'N/A'),
                    item['specific'].get('Job', 'N/A'),
                    item['specific'].get('Revenue', 'N/A'),
                    item['specific'].get('Update-time', 'N/A').replace("-","/").replace("T"," ").replace("Z",""),                   
                    CALLZULU,
                        ])
                print("done")
                CSVcounter += 1
        # sanity check prints
                print(ErrorHours)
                print(WatnTimeC)
                print(CSVcounter)
                print(dateTimeDifferenceInHours)
```

Comment: There are two `for item in data['People']` loops. I suggest you remove the first/outer one.

Comment: made the change, removed the second one, leaving the top one in place, (have updated the code to show this) not its only exporting one entry to the CSV, everything else is still working fine

Comment: The first should be removed, the inner/second should remain.

Comment: that broke it, ive tried it, first it stopped the bit of script that calculates warn time with unbound error, so i tried to move that around and had no luck, either the whole csv export stops working or i get an `UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable` of some description

Comment: Without the inner/second loop the CSV will only have one line With both loops the code will iterate through all the people in the sequence, writing them all to the CSV repeatedly.

Comment: yes, having both was defiantly the way to go but it as you said, however I'm still getting all results in the CSV rather than just the relevant ones, again, the tkinter display and print() commands and everything else is working but when it comes to the CSV for some reason it wants to write everything in the JSON to file. not sure why

Comment: Use the same logic you have for the tkinter display to write to the CSV

Comment: I have, its identical, and working, however the CSV exporter always exports the entire JSON to the CSV, never just the parts of it that everything else displays and works with, i don't understand it, the entire thing is working perfect, but the CSV exporter always exports the entire JSON

Comment: I eventually solved it by creating a new json file as part of the loop that makes the tkinter display, then exporting that to CSV, its a bit clunkier but its working reliably so ill call it a win